# Can't plot on MATLAB

Tags: matlab, plot, matlab-figure

```
clear;
for R=3:18
    x=inv([9 119 0 0 0;
        0 16*R+8 -8 0 0;
        -1 -15 0 -4 4;
        -8 -148 0 40 0;
        0 -1 1 0 0])*[-40;
        0;
        0;
        -600;
        2*R]
    PR=((x(3,1)-x(2,1))^2)/R;
    plot(PR,R), hold on
end
```

We have the code above and we want to plot PR with respect to changing R values from 3 to 18, however even the MATLAB gives the right values for x matrix and for the last R value, 18, the right PR value; it can't plot the graph.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Method 1: Plotting as Dots

To plot each point as a dot the `plot()` line can be changed to `plot(PR,R,'.')`. Using `hold on` will retain the current plot and in this example add a point on every iteration. The `hold on` term is typically used to overlay plots on the same axis. In this case the plots being overlaid are single points.

[image: Plotting as Scatter Plot]

```
for R = 3:18
    x = inv([9 119 0 0 0; 0 16*R+8 -8 0 0; -1 -15 0 -4 4; -8 -148 0 40 0; 0 -1 1 0 0])*[-40; 0; 0; -600; 2*R];
    PR = ((x(3,1)-x(2,1))^2)/R;
    plot(PR,R,'.');
    hold on
end
```

---

### Method 2: Plotting as a Line, Vectorized Approach

To plot as a line the result of `PR` upon every iteration can be stored in an array. This array can be used and plotted against another vector `R` defined over the range 3 to 18. In this case I used the `.-` modifier in the `plot()` line to plot dots/markers at each of the data points. If you wish to only have the line graph the `.-` modifier can be removed.

[image: Plotting as Line]

```
Index = 1;
for R = 3:18
    x = inv([9 119 0 0 0; 0 16*R+8 -8 0 0; -1 -15 0 -4 4; -8 -148 0 40 0; 0 -1 1 0 0])*[-40; 0; 0; -600; 2*R];
    PR(Index) = ((x(3,1)-x(2,1))^2)/R;
    Index = Index + 1;
end

R = (3:18);
plot(PR,R,'.-');
```

**Ran using MATLAB R2019b**